# Отменить последний commit и применить к предпоследнему

Tags: git

Есть коммиты в одной ветке:

```
A - B - C
```

Как сделать из В, С один коммит B'?
Подозреваю, что надо как-то отменить С, без пропажи изменений, и сделать --amend к B.

Comment: > надо как-то отменить С, без пропажи изменений

git reset --soft HEAD~

Comment: @Etki, спасибо

Comment: Вот здесь хорошее решение:  http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/416775

Comment: @NickVolynkin несколько странно смотрится формулировка "Вопрос уже задавался **ранее**" при том, что "оригинальный" вопрос был задан на 3 месяца **позже** этого.

Comment: @Regent: да, я тоже обратил внимание на несоответствие.  Но там есть хороший и принятый ответ, а тут нет. Этим и руководствовался.