# Как разделить/склеить старый комит?

Tags: git, git-rebase

Задачка из области синтетических, нужно для понимания как это делать правильно.

Есть история из 3 коммитов

```
git log --oneline
cccccc change c.txt
bbccaa add new two file (b.txt, c.txt) and change a.txt
aaaaaa add new file a.txt
```

Задача 1: разделить `bbccaa` на два, чтобы результат был

```
git log --oneline
cccccc change c.txt
aaa111 change a.txt
bbbccc add two file (b.txt, c.txt)
aaaaaa add new file a.txt
```

Задача 2: склеить частично `bbbccc` с `aaaaaa`, чтобы вышло

```
git log --oneline
cccccc change c.txt
aaa111 change a.txt
ccc111 add file c.txt
aaabbb add files a.txt b.txt
```

Comment: @nick-volynkin когда правку вносишь, смотри чтоб это не отразилась на ответах, ты в вопросе поменял sha1 коммитов, а в ответах они остались старые.

Comment: @anber ок, спасибо что заметили.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

И то, и другое делается с помощью rebase (самой страшной командой в гите:) ).

Начнем с второго, как более простого.

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

`-i`  - интерактивный режим, HEAD~3 - три последних коммита.

Откроется редактор по умолчанию, где будет список коммитов. Вверху более старые, внизу более свежие (обратно выводу `git log`!) На против каждого будет написано `pick` (то есть, "взять"). Находим коммиты, которые нужно слить и напротив верхнего с пары пишем `s` или `squash`. Сохраняемся. Git сам откатит указанные коммиты, а потом накатит по новому. Коммит-сообщение возьмет с парного коммита. Если нужно его поправить, то напротив него пишем `edit` - при накатывании коммита будет открыто стандартное окно редактора для ввода сообщения коммита.

С разделением чуть сложнее. Для этого выбираем коммит, пишем напротив него edit и сохраняем. Гит откатит коммиты (не только тот, который выбран, и все до самого свежего - это нужно понимать!). И начнет накатывать их по новой. Когда дойдет до того, который помечен edit - вывалится в консоль. В этот момент с помощью git add/git reset (я люблю использовать `git add -i`, если нужно добавить "кусочками") исправить коммит, можно сделать ещё один-другой, а потом дать комманду `git rebase --continue` и гит продолжит накатывать коммиты.
Важно понимать, что sha хэши новых коммитов поменяются.

За дополнительными инструкциями как всегда читайте [справку](http://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8).

Answer (score 3):

Можно сделать с помощью `git rebase -i` как писал @KoVadim, можно откатиться на aaabbb с сохранением изменением в рабочей директории и перекоммитить заново выборочно. 
И то и то при условии что не было push на сервер и другие люди не скачали изменения.