# Как отменить коммит так, чтобы с проектом никаких изменений не произошло?

Tags: git, git-reset, git-rebase

Пытаюсь закоммитить на GitHub большой проект по частям - по 500Мб, постепенно удаляя определенные папки из .gitignore. Пока так делал все было хорошо.

Но случайно закоммитил сразу 1.5Гб, теперь выдает ошибку при синхронизации с GitHub. Как можно отменить этот коммит, чтобы с моим локальным проектом никаких изменений не произошло?

И еще вопрос. Это нормальная практика - коммитить проекты по 5Гб?

Comment: Рекомендуется обходиться проектами не более 1 Gb  объёмом: https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota/

Comment: Думаю, для того, чтобы кто-то мог помочь, стоит описать ситуацию подробнее, например, добавить используемую последовательность действий и полученные сообщения

Comment: Речь об этом репозитории? https://github.com/dmitrykozyr/Home

Comment: Делаю все через интерфейс GitHub:
1. Нажал "Закоммитить"
2. Нажал "Синхронизировать"

Уже часть проекта так загрузил на GitHub, часть еще осталась

Comment: @NickVolynkin Да

Comment: Это абсолютно ненормальная практика, код - это текстовые файлы, и сложно представить себе проект с таким весом. Что у вас там, бинарные данные?

Comment: Игра на Unreal Engine, кода там еще почти нет. Там много тяжелых файлов самого движка и плюс модели

Comment: @dmitrykozyr: а тяжелые файлы самого движка разве не устанавливаются вместе с движком на рабочую машину каждого разработчика?

Comment: @NickVolynkin В Unity я знаю, какие файлы можно не загружать, там у меня меньше гигабайта выходит. А проект на Unreal загружаю впервые. Еще не разобрался, какие каталоги можно не загружать. Но я согласен, что это неправильно

Comment: @dmitrykozyr: значит нужно начать с этого: точно определить, что туда будет входить, а что - нет. Предлагаю вам задать про это отдельный вопрос вида «Что должно быть в .gitignore для Unreal Engine». Отличный вопрос будет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Вариант 1

Решение про возврат к более раннему коммиту есть здесь:

[Как вернуться (откатиться) к более раннему коммиту?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/431520/181472)

В данном случае наиболее удобным мне представляется вариант с **4.1 При этом сохранить изменения в индекс репозитория**

```
git reset --soft 3b61b1
```

Хотя вы можете использовать просто reset и добавлять файлы.

```
git reset 3b61b1
git add ...
git commit -m'part 1'
git add ...
git commit -m'part 2'
...
```

После чего вы разбиваете этот коммит на несколько и делаете push.

#### Вариант 2 - разбить через rebase -i

[Как разделить/склеить старый комит?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416761/181472)

Rebase делаем к коммиту перед тем, который хотим разделять:

```
git rebase -i 3b61b1^
```

#### О репозиториях в 5ГБ

> И еще вопрос. Это нормальная практика - коммитить проекты по 5Гб?

Это возможно, но накладывает определенные ограничения.

[Version control system for game development with UDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285801/version-control-system-for-game-development-with-udk)

[How to use Git for Unity3D source control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18225126/how-to-use-git-for-unity3d-source-control)

Comment: Проект на Unreal Engine, но с Unity тоже есть такие проблемы. Спасибо, почитаю

Answer (score 4):

Скажем, что история коммитов выглядет вот так, где В - ваш HEAD, и (Ф) - состояние ваших файлов.

```
         (ф)
A -> Б -> В
          ↑
        master
```

(1) Если хотите **совсем уничтожить коммит В и больше никогда не видеть его**, то можно так:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

В результат,

```
    (ф)
A -> Б
     ↑
   master
```

В больше не существует. Так как мы использовали `--hard`, превратились к состоянию файлов после коммита Б.

(2) Если хотите **отменить коммит В, но сохранить состояние файлов**, то можно без `--hard`:

```
git reset HEAD~1
```

В результат,

```
         (ф)
A -> Б -> В
     ↑
   master
```

HEAD изменился, но состояние файлов то же самое. Ничего не потеряли.

---

[(Ответ взят с английского сайта)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6866485/546661)