# Объединить commits в github

Tags: git, github, git-commit

У меня есть проект на github - https://github.com/lorents17/iCatalyst

Подскажите, как объединить коммиты?

Comment: Скорее всего, вы имеете в виду `git rebase --interactive` (осторожней с этой штукой, пока не разобрались), но уточните задачу.

Comment: нужно сделать rebase и там есть такая опция squash http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/10/squashing-commits-with-rebase.html

Comment: Благодарю! Тогда буду тестировать на другом проекте.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [разделить/склеить старый комит](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416761/%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%82)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поскольку ваш проект [выложен в открытый доступ](https://github.com/lorents17/iCatalyst) и у него есть 6 форков (и, возможно, ещё сколько-нибудь прямых клонов), то очень важно ответить на следующий вопрос:

> Успели ли вы запушить эти коммиты на удаленный репозиторий?

Если да, то я категорически не рекомендую вам переписывать историю на удаленном репозитории командой `push -f`. (После того, как вы ее перепишете на локальном, объединяя коммиты, `push` будет возможен только с параметром `-f` (forced), который переписывает историю на удаленном.) Это приведет к тому, что все остальные пользователи будут вынуждены делать слияние вручную при следующем пулле.

Подробнее об этом есть в вопросе «[Откатить уже опубликованный коммит и опубликовать новый, не вызывая мержа у других](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/429512/181472)».

В случае, если

- коммиты есть только на вашем локальном репозитории,
- или они есть на удаленном, но там нет других участников,
- или участники есть, но вы их ненавидите,

можно объединять коммиты и выполнять `push -f`.

О том, как это сделать, уже написано ответе Michael P. Bazos, а также в этом вопросе:

[Как разделить/склеить старый комит?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416761/)

Comment: Благодарю Вас! Очень сильно помогли

Comment: @lorents: Пожалуйста. Получилось задачу решить?

Comment: Я просто решил, лучше ничего не трогать.

Answer (score 2):

Допустим `git log` даёт следующий выход, и вы хотите объединить commits под названием **Update iCatalyst.bat** :

```
b536215c2afb1d4e300ba8190216797af4dc35ee Update                <- HEAD
78934a91e9846a67021230908e7773a1d92e5e0f Update iCatalyst.bat  <- объединить с предыдущим
cf7ba9c07a67c7e0c0c6324f7102f765201790d2 Update iCatalyst.bat 
9d4e7e2b664c27486c0dc984bb33f213475308ae update AdvanceComp 1.20
```

Вводим:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

В редакторе будет:

```
pick cf7ba9c Update iCatalyst.bat
pick 78934a9 Update iCatalyst.bat
pick b536215 Update

# Rebase 9d4e7e2..b536215 onto 9d4e7e2
#
# Commands:
#  p, pick = use commit
#  r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
#  e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
#  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
#  f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
#  x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
```

Нам интересует комманды **squash (s)** или просто **fixup (f)**. Первая даёт возможность редактировать лог сообщения, вторая просто объединяет. То есть, если сообщение предыдущего коммита устраивает, просто заменяем `pick` на `fixup` или, короче, на `f`:

```
pick cf7ba9c Update iCatalyst.bat
f 78934a9 Update iCatalyst.bat      <-- заменили pick на f (fixup)
pick b536215 Update
```

С учётом, что эти commits уже на гитхаб нужно будет использовать `push` с опцией `-f` (для *force*)