# git pull после чужого git push --force

Tags: git, git-rebase

Представим что есть история

```
git log --oneline
cccccc change c.txt
aaa111 change a.txt
bbbccc merge other branch (add new file c.txt)
aaaaaa add new file a.txt
```

Это история храниться у 10 человек
Один из членов команды решил убрать коммит aaa111. Он сделал новую историю

```
git log --oneline
ffffff change c.txt
bbbccc merge other branch (add new file c.txt)
aaaaaa add new file a.txt
git push -f original
```

Как правильно или просто остальным 9 членам команды принять эти изменения?

Просто git pull приведет к мерджам и возможно востановлению коммита aaa111. И вообще произойдет каша.

Comment: Узнаю коммиты из http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416761/181472

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно в больших компаниях принято, что если кто то хочет сделать `git push -f`, то он всем обязательно рассказывает, зачем это нужно и получает на это разрешание. И это применяется только в исключительных ситуациях (например, кто то закоммитил удаление всех файлов в репозитории или в публичный репозиторий залили пароли/приватные ключи).

Как я решаю подобные случаи: после того, как я увидел, что мой код мержиться неверно из-за форсированного пуша, я делаю `git reset --hard origin master` (или другая нужная ветка). Но нужно поминить, что это удалит незакомиченные изменения, а также закоммиченные, но конфликтующие изменения будут потеряны (если не сделать себе копию ветки).

Answer (score 0):

Нет, это неправильно. Как уже написал KoVadim, `git push -f` это крайняя мера. В нормальном рабочем процессе это недопустимо, по крайней мере для общих веток вроде `master` и `develop`.

Сейчас для исправления ситуации можно сделать ещё один `git push -f` из репозитория, в котором этот коммит есть. После этого, вероятно, придется разрешать конфликты слияния только одному человеку, но не девяти.

Для того чтобы удалить запушенный коммит, но не переписывать историю, используется `git revert`. Подробнее:

- Диаграмма решений: [Откатить уже опубликованный коммит и опубликовать новый, не вызывая мержа у других](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/429512/181472)
- Как работает `git revert` (см. пункт 5): [Как вернуться (откатиться) к более раннему коммиту?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/431520/181472)

Comment: Я против хранить более запутанную историю в команде, поэтому форспушим по потребностям, но в приделах пулриквестов, после уже ничего не меняем.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько понимаю поможет такая штука:

```
git reset --hard cccccc
```

то есть последний коммит до переписывания истории

потом пишем старую историю заново

```
git push origin +master
```

подробнее можно прочитать тут:

http://tonyganch.com/git/reset/

Comment: что то не так, все наоборот. Последний коммит bbbccc этоже git log и он показывает в обратном порядке. И я не понял зачем делать git push origin +master если члены команды хотят принять изменения а не стереть коммит ffffff

Comment: Я имел ввиду последний коммит до переписывания истории, у меня гитлог как раз показывает последний коммит сверху, но в общем не в этом суть, человеку который переписал историю коммитов нужно вернуться на последний коммит до переписывания, и записать все обратно, судя по коменту к коммиту fffff там изменения в одном файле, поэтому одному человеку который тем более накосячил, проще восстановить историю и после это добавить новый коммит с изменениями в этом файле, а остальные 9 человек в общем то этого и не почувствуют и прекрасно смержатся.